# $x$ in metric space not isolated if and only if for every $r > 0$ the set $B(x, r)$ has infinitely many elements.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

For $(E, d)$ a metric space, a point $x \in E$ is said to be *isolated* if the singleton set $\{x\}$ is open. Show that $x$ in metric space not isolated if and only if for every $r > 0$ the set $B(x, r)$ has infinitely many elements.

---

I started off my proof left to right. If $x$ is not isolated, then $\{x\}$ is not open, meaning there exists some element within $\{x\}$ in which a ball cannot be formed for any radius $r > 0$. Since $x$ is the only element in this set, this must mean that $x$ is this element. And... that's where I'm stuck. I don't know what to do from here.

Comment: Suppose, on the contrary, that  for some $r>0$, $B(x,r)$ contains only finitely many elements…...

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is isolated then there is a ball $B(x,r)$ which only contains $x$, so in particular is finite.

For the other direction, suppose that there exists some $r>0$ such that $B(x,r)$ contains only finitely many elements. If it only contains $x$ then $\{x\}=B(x,r)$ is open and we are done.

Otherwise let $x_1,\dots,x_n$ be the elements besides $x$ contained in $B(x,r)$, and define
$$ \delta=\min\{d(x_1,x),\dots,d(x_n,x)\}$$
Note that $0<\delta<r$.

I claim that the ball $B(x,\frac{\delta}{2})$ contains only $x$. Indeed, if $x\neq y\in B(x,\frac{\delta}{2})$, then $d(x,y)<\frac{\delta}{2}<r$, hence $y\in B(x,r)$, so $y$ is one of $x_1,\dots,x_n$. But then $d(x,y)\geq \delta$ by the choice of $\delta$, which is a contradiction.

Therefore we have shown that $B(x,\frac{\delta}{2})=\{x\}$, so $\{x\}$ is open.